# Executing shell scripts from a web browser in linux

Tags: shell, scripting, ubuntu, apache2, cgi

Well I've been assigned this task, and I haven't a clue where to start. I'm running Ubuntu, and so far I've only managed to get apache2 working.

Now it would be very grateful if anyone could guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to configure apache to execute CGI scripts.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html

Comment: Ok i've done that...for example if i want to use the 'ls' command, then how would i go about using the cgi script as u said

Answer (score 1):

I've posted a very similar question over on webmasters.stackexchange and received a great answer that should get you going: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11019/adding-custom-handlers